# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, blur

Before I ask, I have searched this question on stackoverflow and other sites as well, most of them mentioned that your "this" didn't point to the thing you are trying to get value from.

That was because most of them had a different function being called from the element they were targeting. My case is however a little different and that didn't solve my question,

My HTML code is a form, in which one field is of username and has this code,

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
                     <input type="text" id = "t_username" name="t_username" placeholder="Enter Teacher Username" value="" class="form-control" >
                     </div>
                     <span id = "availability"></span>
```

My JQuery code is as follows

```
 $('#t_username').blur(function()
      {
        var username = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
          url: "action.php", 
          method: "POST", 
          data: {user_name: t_username}, 
          dataType: "text", 
          success:function(html)
          {
            $('#availability').html(html); 
          }
        });
      });
```

And my PHP code is as follows,

```
if (isset ($_POST['username']))
{
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  if ($db->username_check($user) != 0) // $db is an object of Database class 
  {
    echo '<span class = "text-danger">Username already exists</span>';
  }
  else 
  {
        echo '<span class = "text-success">Username is available</span>';
  }

}
```

My SQL function is (defined in a class)

```
public function username_check($user)
    {
      $sql = "SELECT * from tbl_teacher where username = :user";
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(['user'=>$user]);
      $t_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
      return $t_rows;
    }
```

I have tried using these two things, but I still got the same error. Can anyone help me solve this please?

I have tried (but with no good result)

```
var username = $(this.target).val();   -> This called an error of exceeded stack limit (because of some never ending recursive function I think) 

var username = $('#t_usernmae').val(); -> This did the same exceeded stack limit error
```

I have also tried changing my function as,

```
$(#'t_username').on("blur", function(){.....*Everything here* ..... });
```

[JS Fiddle of the code (I don't know how to create it, but I have shared a bit of code here)](https://jsfiddle.net/peqzw4rv/)

Comment: The last one is a syntax error. But other than that, did you try `$(this).val()`? A [mcve] will be very helpful. The problem lies only with JavaScript / FrontEnd, the PHP code seems alright.

Comment: What is the actual problem ? Sorry your question does not make any sense on what you are to achieve and where are you using `toLowerCase`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that's the problem, I haven't used any toLowerCase function anywhere in my code. The problem is, I am trying to validate if the username is already taken or not using AJAX, and it is giving this error whenever I "lose focus" from the "username" field when trying to test the code.

Comment: @SakibKhan Can you make a [mcve] as this isn't reproducible from my end.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I think I have given enough code? I am totally ok to providing a full code here, but that would be long and unnecessary.. I think my problem lies in some of the small syntax (most probably related to "this") and that's what I am trying to seek help in.... and yes, $(this).val() should work but it is not (I have used $(this).val() in my code as shared above)

Comment: @SakibKhan Agreed. With whatever you have given, I couldn't replicate it. Also, this `$(#'t_username')` should be replaced with `$('#t_username')`, let me know if it works.

Comment: @SakibKhan Instead of providing full code, can you please add a runnable snippet?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes sorry I tried $('#t_username') and it didn't work. Mistakenly type $(#'t_username') in the post... I have also provided one JS fiddle at the end, I have no idea how to make this thing so it most probably is incorrect. Sorry :/

Comment: @SakibKhan See the working solution below.

Comment: Yep, that's a typo.

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery Validate tag when the question has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not using the passing the `data` correctly.

You would need to use `username` but instead you were using `t_username` which will be `undefined` and not `maximum call stack size exceeded` or `toLowerCase` error will thrown in the console.

Change your `ajax` jQuery code to this. All should be fine.

```
$('#t_username').blur(function() {

  //Username
  var username = $(this).val();
  
  console.log(username)
  
  //Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      user_name: username  //this needed a fix
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(html) {
      $('#availability').html(html);
    }
  });
});
```